# I cant access the form "name" or "value" in request.POST in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

My template contents multiple forms with multiple buttons.

I've read these topics:

[Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)

[How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form)

[How can I access the form submit button value in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607091/how-can-i-access-the-form-submit-button-value-in-django)

and I did exactly the same, included "name" and "value" in form's input (tried with button tag too)

but the "name" attribute doesn't exist in POST request. What am i doing wrong?

template:

```
<div class="container" align="center" style="border: solid 3px red">
    <h3>Form 1</h3>
    <form id="form_step_1" method="post" action="{% url 'ajax_order_data' %}" align="center">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ FormStep1 }}
            <button type="submit" name="step_1" value="step_1">button_step1</button>
    </form>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container" align="center"  style="border: solid 3px red">
    <h3>Form 2</h3>
    <form id="form_step_2" method="post" action="{% url 'ajax_order_data' %}" align="center">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ FormStep2 }}
            <button type="submit" name="step_2" value="step_2">button_step2</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var form_1 = $("#form_step_1");
    var form_2 = $("#form_step_2");

    form_1.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(form_1).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: form_1.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {smth_1}
        })
    });

    form_2.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(form_2).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: form_2.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {smth_2}
        })
    });
</script>
```

view:

```
def somefunc(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'step_1' in request.POST:
```

Comment: you have to add `return render(request, template_name.html)` at the end

Answer (score 2):

You've explicitly disabled the normal form submission process, and are sending the data as JSON in your Ajax. So you can't use the normal methods of handling form-encoded data in Django, because you haven't got any.

Instead, you need to deserialise the body of the request, which will give you a dict:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
if 'step_1' in data:
```