# JQuery .on(click) event handler not stopping submit when <input type="submit"> element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `form` with a `table` inside it. The table has four `input` elements each with `type=submit`. The form also has a hidden `input` element. What I want to do is the following:

When one of the four `input` elements is clicked, a jQuery event should fire that:

- Stops submission
- Sets the id of the clicked element as the value of the hidden input
- Submits the form

The event is not firing and the form is being submitted normally. I can't see what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="" style="background-color: antiquewhite; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="op" name="op" value="">
  <table align="center" style="width: 100%;" border="1" style="background-color: antiquewhite; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <h3>Is this an <i>origin</i> for the <i>claim?</i></h3>
      </td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="1" value="Yes"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="2" value="No"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" id="3" value="Invalid Input"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="4" value="Don't Know"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

```js
$("input").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let choice = e.target.id;
  document.getElementById("op").value = choice;
  $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Given that the `value` of the button that's clicked will be sent in the request if you give it a `name` attribute, why not just do that, and remove all the unnecessary JS and hidden field(s)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you can show me how would I get that value in Django (which is where I am submitting this form) I can just do that. Otherwise I am stuck as I have no idea how to get it from Django.

Comment: You receive it in the exact same way you would the `op` value right now, you just change `op` to whatever you name the buttons

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607091/how-can-i-access-the-form-submit-button-value-in-django

Comment: Is your table generated *after* your jquery `$("input").on("click...` has run?  Change to `$(document).on('click', 'input', function() ...`  (maybe give them a class to be clearer, `$(document).on('click', 'input.button', function() ...`

Comment: Or use a `<button type='button'` then there's no worry that it will "submit"

Comment: Might even just be that you need to wrap your click handler in doc ready:  `$(function() { $("input").on("click"....`

Comment: `return false;`

Comment: @FlashThunder that's what `e.preventDefault();` does (more or less), except `e.preventDefault();` as the first line also works when there's a script error and the `return false` doesn't get hit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I ended up just using the value of the buttons. Works fine

Comment: @freedomn-m The script tags with the JQuery are before the table, but I wait for both table and function to load before clicking.

Comment: There's your problem them.  Move the code to the end or wrap it in doc ready.  Or use event delegation.   When you run `$("input"..` it only affects the elements that exist at the time the code runs - in your case, before they exist.

Comment: While not strictly "dynamically created" elements, this also applies to "elements created after the code runs": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

causes the submission of the form, even though you have earlier prevented the default button click submission with the line

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and just attach it to your inputs

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post" action="" style="background-color: antiquewhite; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="op" name="op" value="">
  <table align="center" style="width: 100%;" border="1" style="background-color: antiquewhite; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <h3>Is this an <i>origin</i> for the <i>claim?</i></h3>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="custom-trigger" id="1" value="Yes"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="custom-trigger" id="2" value="No"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="custom-trigger" id="3" value="Invalid Input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="custom-trigger" id="4" value="Don't Know"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and then just get it in the js

```
$(".custom-trigger").on('click', function(e) {
   let choice = e.target.id;
   document.getElementById("op").value = choice;
  $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Doing that you won't need to submit the form until it is ready with what you need.