# how can i filter eCommerce category and put links in Django Nav bar

Tags: python, django, categories

dears. I wanna filter my product buy categories and show them into navbar dynamically.
so this is my view in the base application

```
def shop_page(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'ecommerce/index_shop.html', context)
```

and this is my base navbar.html

```
<ul class="site-menu js-clone-nav d-none d-lg-block">
              <li class="has-children active">
                <a href="{% url 'ecommerce:shop_page'%}">Shop</a>
               
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <!-- {%for item in category.item.all%}
                  <li><a href="{{item.category.all}}">{{item.get_category_display}}</a></li>
                  {%endfor%} -->

                   <li><a href="#">Clothes and Uniforms</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Phones & Accessories</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jewelry & Watches</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bags & Shoes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Beauty & Health, Hair</a></li> 
                </ul>
```

I wanna add automatically categories in the navbar and put filtering when user click on a category name

so please check my project on [github.com](https://github.com/Mratashnejad/Viva-dealers-thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is to have everything rendered in the context, and then you render it in HTML. For example:

```py
class HomePageView(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['cat'] = ['clothes', 'bags', 'uniforms']
```

and then you can render it in your HTML as such:

```html
<ul class="...">
  {% for category in cat %}
    <li>{{ category }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As for the filters, you might want to assign your button a form action, and then you return it as a part of your context.

```py
if 'bags' in request.POST:
    context['items'] = Obj.objects.all.filter(name="bags")
```

```html
<!-- must be a submit button -->
<form action="..." method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="bags" value="List Objects" />
</form>
```

after this, you will only get the items. You might want to do some amendments as I don't have your full code, but this is briefly how it works.

Although keep in mind, you must have at least 2 buttons in the second HTML form (the one with buttons) as it doesn't work with only 1 button otherwise there is no point... you can look at the explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220034/13912230).

Comment: dear your document , it's good, but I don't understand what  am should be do

Comment: please check my project on GitHub link

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `charfield()` under your product model (or whatever its name is in your project) and call it category, this field should be filled with the type of category of the product uploaded with each product being added.

and specify a template for each category, then you can do the filtering in the template as follows.

example.html:

```
{% for product in products %}
   {% if product.category == example(whatever the name of the category is) %}
       {{ product.title }}
       {{ product.price }}
   {% emdif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Bonus idea: If you have a certain amount of categories (which is most probable) you can put all the categories in a drop down list which (which will replace the `charfield()`) for the person posting a product to choose from when uploading a new product