# 'name' in request.POST always returns False - django : python

Tags: python, django

I've a view, with two forms, i want to check which one will be submit, using `'bookingformbtn' in request.POST` and `'visitorformbtn' in request.POST` but both returns false ?! i've to keep both forms in different  tag, and the suggested question doesnt work! please i you know something about that let me know ..
here is my views

```
def my_views_post(request):
    print('bookingformbtn' in request.POST)#returns False
    print('visitorformbtn' in request.POST)#returns False
    # non of these conditions works !
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax() and 'visitorformbtn' in request.POST:
         #do something
    elif request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST' and 'bookingformbtn' in request.POST:
         #do something else
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="mt-2" id="add_new_guestform">{% csrf_token %}
<--! form inputs -->
                <input type="submit" name="visitorformbtn" value=" "save">

</form>

<form method="POST" class="mt-2" id="post-form-add-booking">{% csrf_token %}
<--! form inputs -->
            <input  name="bookingformbtn" type="submit"  value="save">


</form>
```

is there something i did wrong please ?!
thank you for your advice ..

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220034/354577)

Comment: but i have two different form, i want to keep it separate from each other, so i can use only one button per form! is is still should work ? thank you

Comment: Then you might want two different view functions. Based on the names of your forms they appear to do very different things. Give each its own [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action).

Comment: but isnot  possible two views with the same url, and i must keep it, both forms in the same url

Comment: @Chris please how to use it, can you give an example please

Comment: There are a few ways you could proceed. A common option would be to send the request using JavaScript (to unique URLs for each form) instead of refreshing the whole page. But if you really want to keep this all in one view function (which, again, I advise against) you could have a hidden input in each form that specifies which form you're submitting.